# How to get submenu In Pyqt5 .ui file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to get the submenu That is QuitProgram <- This is name of submenu but it is in UI file.

How can I get it in a variable set its action to quit program?

File menu object name is 'actionQuit_FromProgram' <- This is a submenu.

Python File:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
import os
import qdarkgraystyle
path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
import qrcode

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Ui, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('main.ui', self)
    #self.show()
    self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'qrgenerator')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.QrCodeGenerator) # Remember to pass the definition/method, not the return value!
    self.input = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'qredit')
    self.button1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'qropen')
    self.button1.clicked.connect(self.OpenQRCode)
    self.menu1 = self.findChild(QMenuBar,'actionQuit_FromProgram')
    print(self.menu1)
    #self.menu1.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)
    self.show()

def QrCodeGenerator(self):
    # Generate QR code
    self.url = qrcode.make(self.qredit.text())
    if self.qredit.text() == '':
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Please Type In Something To Generate Qr Code")
    else:
        self.url.save("filename.png","PNG")
def OpenQRCode(self):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
    path,"Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.png *.svg)")[0]
    self.label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap(fname))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `loadUi` (or `setupUi` if you're using files generated by pyuic), all elements in the object inspector (the tree view that lists all widgets on your UI) become available as instance attributes, according to their [object name](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop).

So, if your action is called `actionQuit_FromProgram` in the inspector, you can directly access it using `self.actionQuit_FromProgram`.

This also means that:

- all those `findChild` are absolutely useless: you already have access to `self.qrgenerator`, `self.qredit`, etc;
- in any case, `findChild` should be used with the correct class of the object you're looking for: I sincerely doubt that `actionQuit_FromProgram` is a QMenuBar (so, using `findChild(QMenuBar, ...)` won't work at all; if it is an action, use `findChild(QAction, ...)`; if it's a submenu, use `findChild(Qmenu, ...)`;
- there's usually just *one* menu bar for each QMainWindow, and it is easily accessible using [`self.menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar);